# IntelliJ - No out folder

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, version-control

This might be a trivial question, but i can't solve it. 
I have cloned a git repository, where the "out" folder was excluded (As it's supposed to), but i can't run the code.

It gives me an error called

"Error:java: /production/nameOfProject: does not exist"

I have narrowed the problem down to something with the project structure, and i have specified my "src" folder as the source folder, but i don't know what to do about the "paths"-section. Can't i get intelliJ to create the out folders automatically?

A temporary work around is to create the project again and import the modules, and here intelliJ creates the "out" folders, and the code compiles, but that can't be the right way.

This is how my intelliJ project structure modules look, if that helps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO0Js.jpg

Thank you.

Comment: You should write to the project(repo) owner to fix it.

Comment: How is it supposed to be fixed? I think the correct way to share a repo is excluding the out folder, like the owner has done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by cloning the repository, and then i choose to "create a new project from existing sources", and picked the cloned repository. intellij even discovered the src-folders itself.

Answer (score 1):

you can see how to build artifacts here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html#package

When you make some new artifacts, then go into Build -> Build Artifacts...

IntelliJ will automatically generate out files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just create new folder called "out" in project structure and mark it as excluded.

Have you created this from intellij vcs import?

Comment: I recreated the project through vcs import, and that did the trick. Also it seems like i had created the out folder in the wrong places.